# How can I turn dataframe rows into headers?

Tags: python, pandas

I have some data on each of the first 151 pokemon in 151 different dataframes.

```
    id  identifier  pokemon_id  stat_id base_stat   local_language_id   name
36  7   Squirtle    7   1   44  9   HP
37  7   Squirtle    7   2   48  9   Attack
38  7   Squirtle    7   3   65  9   Defense
39  7   Squirtle    7   4   50  9   Special Attack
40  7   Squirtle    7   5   64  9   Special Defense
41  7   Squirtle    7   6   43  9   Speed


    id  identifier  pokemon_id  stat_id base_stat   local_language_id   name
18  4   Charmander  4   1   39  9   HP
19  4   Charmander  4   2   52  9   Attack
20  4   Charmander  4   3   43  9   Defense
21  4   Charmander  4   4   60  9   Special Attack
22  4   Charmander  4   5   50  9   Special Defense
23  4   Charmander  4   6   65  9   Speed
```

What I would really like is one row per pokemon with each stat as a column of a new dataframe.  Something like

```
id    identifier    pokemon_id   HP  Attack    ...
4     Charmander    4            39  52        ...
7     Squirtle      7            44  48        ...
```

Is there an easy way to do that with a pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 4):

I believe this will do what you're after:

```
df.groupby(['id', 'identifier', 'name']).base_stat.first().unstack('name')
```

Comment: A group/unstack is basically the same as a pivot table.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
df = df.pivot_table(index=['id','identifier'], 
                    columns='name', 
                    values='base_stat', 
                    aggfunc='first')

print (df)
name           Attack  Defense  HP  Special Attack  Special Defense  Speed
id identifier                                                             
7  Squirtle        48       65  44              50               64     43
```

If all `DataFrames` are in list `dfs`, use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with `list comprehension`:

```
dfs = [df1, df2]

df = pd.concat([df.pivot_table(index=['id','identifier'], 
                               columns='name', 
                               values='base_stat', 
                               aggfunc='first') for df in dfs])
print (df)
name           Attack  Defense  HP  Special Attack  Special Defense  Speed
id identifier                                                             
7  Squirtle        48       65  44              50               64     43
4  Charmander      52       43  39              60               50     65
```

Last use `reset_index` with [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#changes-to-rename) (new in `pandas` `0.18.0`), if use `pandas bellow 0.18.0` omit `rename_axis` and use `df.columns.name = None`:

```
df = pd.concat([df.pivot_table(index=['id','identifier'], 
                               columns='name', 
                               values='base_stat', 
                               aggfunc='first') for df in dfs])
                  .reset_index()
                  .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print (df)
   id  identifier  Attack  Defense  HP  Special Attack  Special Defense  Speed
0   7    Squirtle      48       65  44              50               64     43
1   4  Charmander      52       43  39              60               50     65
```